# Exiting loop prematurely in VBA

Tags: excel, for-loop, vba

My loop seems to be exiting prematurely. Basically,  I would like the following conditions:

When WC(j-1)+WCinit*dz is reater than pwp
if fc-WC(j-1)+WCinit+RefEF*dz is less than Precip *dz

then runoff and percolation equal  precip-fc- (WC+WCinit)+RefET*dz*0.5
and WJ(j)=fc

else
runoff and percolation=0
and WC(j)=WC(j-1)+WCinit+precip-RefET*dz

BUT if WC(j - 1) + WCinit(i) <= pwp 
then prin WC(j)=pwp

I would like the entire loop to end when i and j =12

The loop seems to be ending when j=2

```
Dim fc As Double
fc = Cells(4, 7).Value
NumMonth = 12
i = 1
j = 2
Dim pwp As Double
pwp = Cells(4, 8).Value
Dim dz As Double
dz = 0.5    'm

While (WC(j - 1) + WCinit(i) * dz > pwp * dz) And (j <= NumMonth)
    If (fc - (WC(j - 1) + WCinit(i)) + RefET(i) * dz) < (Precip(i) * dz) Then
        Runoff(i) = (Precip(i) - fc - (WC(j - 1) + WCinit(i)) + RefET(i) * dz) * 0.5
        Percolation(i) = (Precip(i) - fc - (WC(j - 1) + WCinit(i)) + RefET(i) * dz) * 0.5
        WC(j) = fc

    Else
        Runoff(i) = 0
        Percolation(i) = 0
        WC(j) = WC(j - 1) + WCinit(i) + Precip(i) - RefET(i) * dz

    End If
    j = j + 1
    i = i + 1

Wend
If WC(j - 1) + WCinit(i) <= pwp Then
    Runoff(i) = 0
    Percolation(i) = 0
    WC(j) = pwp
End If
```

Comment: If j = 2 after the `Wend`, then you're never entering the `While` loop, since j = 2 before you start. Since `j <= NumMonth` is clearly true at the beginning of your loop, the other While condition - `WC(j - 1) + WCinit(i) * dz > pwp * dz` is false the first time it's encountered, and so you never enter the loop.    You should step through your code using F8 to check this.

Comment: Also, I don't see where your array (or variant) variables `WC` and `WCinit` are declared or initialized. They are aren't they?

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on how to fix this? switch the order of the loop? I have been stepping through my code and I understand this is happening, however, I am new to VBA and dont know where to go from here.

Comment: Yes, they are declared publicly. I didnt include my entire code, it is quite long.

Comment: And are they initialized? Do they have values in them? If not, your `While` statement will fail the first time, because `WC(j - 1) + WCinit(i) * dz` will equal 0 and will be less than `pwp * dz` unless Cells(4, 8).Value is less than 0. At least that's what it looks like.

Comment: yes, I have checked my read sub, all the arrays have values. While (WC(j - 1) + WCinit(i) * dz EQUALS 0.1> pwp * dz EQUALS 0.1) And (j <= NumMonth), so the while statement fails the first time. I thought it would skip down to the wend, and then for the next i and j start up at the beginning of the while loop again?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25020/discussion-between-doug-glancy-and-user1977802)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we discussed in the comments, the code never enters the `While` loop, because the first part of the condition `WC(j - 1) + WCinit(i) * dz` is never true. The second part, `j <= NumMonth`, clearly is true.

To have this work, and be able to increment j until the `While` condition is true, you'll need a  different type of loop, maybe a Do Until. See this [MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eked04a7.aspx).